Training fasterrcnn_resnet50_fpn on visdrone dataset
I am trying to finetune the model fasterrcnn_resnet50_fpn from PyTorch on visdrone dataset for an Object Detection task. After some time from the beginning of the training loop, I got the following Error:

On GPU: RuntimeError: NVML_SUCCESS == r INTERNAL ASSERT FAILED at "../c10/cuda/CUDACachingAllocator.cpp":830, please report a bug to PyTorch.
On CPU: AssertionError: All bounding boxes should have positive height and width. Found invalid box [290.4849853515625, 220.80001831054688, 295.81500244140625, 220.80001831054688] for target at index 0.

Here is the code:

Dataset class

class VisDroneDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, annotations_df:pd.DataFrame, images_dir:Path,
                 transforms:Optional[Callable]=None):
        self.transforms = transforms
        self.image_paths = sorted(images_dir.iterdir())
        self.df = annotations_df

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.image_paths)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        image_path = self.image_paths[idx]
        image_id = image_path.stem
        annotations = self.df[self.df['image_id'] == image_id]

        image = Image.open(image_path).convert("RGB")
        boxes = annotations.iloc[:, 1:-1].values
        labels = annotations.iloc[:, -1].values

        boxes_tensor = torch.tensor(boxes, dtype=torch.float32)
        labels_tensor = torch.tensor(labels, dtype=torch.int64)

        target = {
            "boxes": boxes_tensor,
            "labels": labels_tensor
        }
        
        if self.transforms:
            image, target = self.transforms(image, target)

        return T.ToTensor()(image), target



I downloaded the dataset from Here and processed the annotation files into one pandas DataFrame. The final shape of the annotations looks as follows:




image_id
bbox_x1
bbox_y1
bbox_x2
bbox_y2
label




*000014
684
8
957
124
0


*000014
606
119
671
189
0


*000014
...
...
...
...
...


*000014
329
161
336
171
2


...
...
...
...
...
...




DataLoader

def collate_fn(batch):
    return list(zip(*batch))

train_dataset = VisDroneDataset(train_annotations_df, train_images_path)
train_data_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=2, shuffle=True, num_workers=4, 
collate_fn=collate_fn)


Model initialization

weights = FasterRCNN_ResNet50_FPN_Weights.DEFAULT
model = torchvision.models.detection.fasterrcnn_resnet50_fpn(weights=weights)

num_classes = 12

in_features = model.roi_heads.box_predictor.cls_score.in_features
model.roi_heads.box_predictor = FastRCNNPredictor(in_channels=in_features, num_classes=num_classes)

model.to(device)


Training

params = [p for p in model.parameters() if p.requires_grad]
optimizer = optim.SGD(params, lr=0.005, momentum=0.9, weight_decay=0.0005)
lr_scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer,
                                               step_size=3,
                                               gamma=0.1)
num_epochs = 5

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    model.train()
    epoch_loss = 0
    for images, targets in train_data_loader:
        images = list(img.to(device) for img in images)
        targets = [{k: v.to(device) for k, v in t.items()} for t in targets]
        
        loss_dict = model(images, targets)
        
        losses = sum(loss for loss in loss_dict.values())
        epoch_loss += losses
        
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        losses.backward()
        optimizer.step()

    lr_scheduler.step()

    print(f"Epoch {epoch} finished, loss={epoch_loss}")

I run some data analysis on the annotations DataFrame, I checked the minimums of the bbox_* columns and I found all of them > 0, along with the differences between bbox_x2, bbox_x1 and between bbox_y2, bbox_y1 also > 0.
I do not know what is wrong, please help!

“ please report a bug to PyTorch” sounds like pretty decent advice
